# How to do a pull request on github without a merge commit

Tags: git, github

1 Month ago i forked a repository. Didnt do any changes to it and today I want to update my fork to lates source from the repository i forked it from.

I issue a pull request from source to my own fork and press merge commit and accept.

Then I end up with my fork being one commit ahead of master.  Is there any way to not get this : "Merge pull request ..... " in my commit history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a local repository to pull from the original and push to the fork.  See [Syncing a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/).  Seems like the only way.